# Ubuntu version with Asus Motherboard

Tags: asus, versions

I have a computer with Motherboard Asus P7P55-M, and I need to know which Ubuntu version is compatible with it. I am also using an intel i5 750 processor with memories of 1333 MHz DDR3. Thancks

Comment: It will probably run any of them if you have enough memory.  1333 MHz is the speed of the memory, but how much does the machine have?

Comment: We can't answer unless we have info on the specs of the computer

Comment: Without knowing how much RAM you are planning on having installed, any answer has a 50% chance of being wrong (either something will work, or it won’t). Compatibility is also moot if the system is just too darn slow to be responsive enough for the tasks thrown at it. It may be better to ask a search engine about minimum requirements of the distros you would like to use, then see which one most closely aligns with your hardware given the purpose of the machine 

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS hosts slightly older packages, but would be supported until 2025. Ubuntu 21.10 has newer packages, but would be supported until July 2022. Both should work in this laptop, assuming you have 4 GB RAM or greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intel I5-750 is a quad-core 64-bit processor operating at 2.66 GHz.  The ASUS P7P55-M motherboard will support a maximum of 16 GB of system memory.  Depending upon how much memory you have, you should be able to install most flavors of Ubuntu.

But you can also test it out for yourself before installing.  Just download the ISO for any version and put it onto a [USB flash drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB%20Installation%20Media).  You can then boot from the flash drive and test out the version on your specific hardware.

---

The minimum [system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download) are:

- 64-bit dual-core 2 GHz processor
- 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
- ~25 GB of storage space on HDD/SSD
- VGA capable video resolution of 1024x768
- USB port for installer media

Other flavors of Ubuntu require fewer system resources.  In particular, [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) used to target low system resource machines.  As of 18.04, they no longer specifically target "older machines".  They will discontinue support of 32-bit processors after the 18.04 release.  Many 10 year old machines, though, support 64-bit processing making [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) a good choice for low resource computers.

Another option is [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download/).  The minimum [system requirements](https://xubuntu.org/requirements/) are:

- Intel or AMD 64-bit dual-core 1.5 Ghz processor
- 1 GiB RAM (system memory) not shared with video
- 2 GiB RAM (system memory) with integrated graphics
- ~20 GB of storage space on HDD/SSD

But Ubuntu will also run on the Raspberry-Pi and some other ARM processors.
The requirements for the [Raspberry-Pi](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) version are:

- a Raspberry Pi 4 for the desktop version
- a Raspberry Pi 2,3,4 for the server or core versions

Comment: Thanck you for the answers and the comments. I am planning to use the computer for quantum chemistry calculations using software Orca and Gamess, I have 10 Gb of Ram memory. Following Bovine's answer I will try versión 20.04 using a USB flash drive. Also I will perform Atmospheric Chemistry calculations with Geos Chem software. This last software is the one with more system requirements.

Comment: Looking at the [Geos Chem system requirements](http://wiki.seas.harvard.edu/geos-chem/index.php/GEOS-Chem_required_hardware), it shows minimum of 8 - 15 GB of system memory.  And some simulations will require 30 - 40 GB.  Depending on what you want to do with this software, your current hardware may not be up for the task.